# Iterating through json queryset

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, django-queryset

I have an Ajax searchform, which is currently correctly returning the username and profile image of users queried as follows:

```
[{"username": "bugfixtest1", "userprofileinfo__profile_pic": "user-icon.png"}, {"username": "test", "userprofileinfo__profile_pic": "placeholder.jpg"}, {"username": "testemailsend", "userprofileinfo__profile_pic": null}, {"username": "testwithoutprofile", "userprofileinfo__profile_pic": null}]
```

However I am now trying to loop through each of these and output the result as HTML. The following doesn't seem to work however:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/search-users/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          'Q': text
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          var item = data.usersearchresult
          $.each(item.DATA, function(index,item) {
            $('#search_results').html('<li>' + item.username + ' </li>');
         });
```

I have also tried:

```
    success: function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data['usersearchresult'].length; i++){
            $('#search_results').html('<li>' + data['usersearchresult'][i] + ' </li>');
      }
    }
```

Neither of these seem to work however?

Comment: from where did you got `usersearchresult` ? your json doesn't have any such field?

Comment: @Swati from my django view - 
`qs_json = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)`
`return JsonResponse({'usersearchresult': qs_json`
This is working fine as the json is rendering in the template, I just can't pull out the items

Comment: You can directly pass `data` inside for loop .i.e :`$.each(data, function(index,item) {
            $('#search_results').append('<li>' + item.username + ' </li>');
         });` .Also use `append` instead of `html` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised the problem. If anyone's experiencing a similar issue, the json was being output as a string rather than json object.

Adding the following fixed it:

```
var item = data.usersearchresult
var parsed = JSON.parse(item);

for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++){....
```